# MVC linq to sql sum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, decimal, nullable

Trying to get the values returned from a database based on the sum of a field.

But getting this message:

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

It is valid for the database to contain no records for that user for that day, hence I went down the nullable route. In the good old days I would have built a Stored Procedure with `ISNULL` in it!!!

This is the basic expression I have:

`decimal? foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods.Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid).Sum(uf=>(decimal?)uf.quantityAmount ?? 0m);`

Googling it came up with the nullable definitions and use of the ?? with the "m" as it's decimal. But still the error persists!

Your collective help will be invaluable as ever. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb356814(v=vs.100).aspx) method. This will fill in a 0 if no value at all can be found.

```
decimal foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods
    .Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid)
    .Select(uf => uf.quantityAmount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum();
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Maarten, this did the trick. Still a lot to learn on linq to sql!

Answer (score 3):

Use `Convert.ToDecimal()`, this will handle your null issue.

```
decimal foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods.Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate 
                                                     && uf.userID == thisGuid)
                                           .Sum(uf=> Convert.ToDecimal(uf.quantityAmount ?? 0m));
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal
>   ToDecimal(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

**Edit:**

```
decimal foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods.Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate 
                                                     && uf.userID == thisGuid)
                                           .Sum(uf=> { decimal result;
                                                       decimal.TryParse(uf.quantityAmount,out result); 
                                                       return result;});
```

Comment: I had tried that previously but just tried it again and get this error message:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @stumcc: I have updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a `sum` and not `average` you don't really mind null-values?
Why not simply removing the null-values?

```
    decimal? foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods
      .Where(uf => 
         uf.dateAdded == thisDate && 
         uf.userID == thisGuid && 
         uf.quantityAmount != null)
      .Sum(uf=> uf.quantityAmount);
```

Comment: Basically I'm looking for certains foods somebody has eaten on a day. So it may be that that person hasn't eaten those foods, hence the sum of the amount will be 0 as they don't exist on the table.

Comment: Yes, but in this case null should be converted to 0, which would be equal to not counting it at all. Therefore excluding it in the where-clause would escape the problem entirely, but still give the same sum. Also, it avoids any convertions of types in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion originates from the fact the `Sum` in LINQ To Entities is processed a bit different than in LINQ To Objects. Although from declaration it looks like that calling it on a let say `decimal` will return 0, when the target set is empty actually the SQL `SUM` function returns `NULL`, even if the target column is not nullable.

Once you know that, there are two ways of resolving it.

Let say we have a table with `decimal` column and the original expression is

```
table.Sum(item => item.Column)
```

First way is to convert it using the pattern contained in the [Maarten answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941830/mvc-linq-to-sql-sum/34941993#34941993):

```
table.Select(item => item.Column).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()
```

The second way is to explicitly convert the non nullable type to nullable inside the function and then apply *null-coalescing operator* to the **result**:

```
table.Sum(item => (decimal?)item.Column) ?? 0
```

Both ways work and produce one and the same result, so use the one that better suits your personal preferences.

For completeness, applying the second approach in your case would be to basically move the `?? 0` outside of the `Sum` call:

```
decimal foodCount = dbContext.fad_userFoods
    .Where(uf => uf.dateAdded == thisDate && uf.userID == thisGuid)
    .Sum(uf => (decimal?)uf.quantityAmount) ?? 0;
```