# ASP.NET MVC Linq query to SQL DB return Sum by Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have DB with table that contains Scores of students. Every record contains StudentName (nvarchar) and Score (int from 1 to 5) and other data related to record (date, discipline name etc)

```
------------------------------------------------

StudentName   Score   Discipline  Date

Bob             5        Asp.net       05/23/21
Bob             5        Html          05/23/21
Bob             5        C#            05/23/21
John            4        Asp.net       05/23/21
John            4        C#            05/23/21
Michael         3        Asp.net       05/23/21
Michael         3        Html          05/23/21
Michael         4        C#            05/23/21
```

I am trying to return result view where all students will be visible with Sum of their Scores by Name.

```
---------------------------

StudentName   ScoreSum

Bob             15
John            8
Michael         10
```

I've tried following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941830/mvc-linq-to-sql-sum), but getting error with &&:

> Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'type' and 'type'
> Code is part of Controller and **public ActionResult ViewStudentsBySumOfScore()** is a method of it.

```
public ActionResult ViewStudentsBySumOfScore()
{
var db = new AllDbContext();
var ScoreSum = db.Scores
.Select(x =\> x.StudentName && x.Score)
.Sum();

            return View();
        }
```

how to change code to get result as mentioned above?

Comment: In C#, types are paramount. Do you know what `&&` does? What types does it accept? What types are `StudentName` and `Score`? Also, your error message appears to be generic and not the actual error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to group all score records by `StudentName` before creating one object per student and using `.Sum()` to generate the score sum for each student.

If you have a class for storing the score sum for a student, e.g. `StudentScoreSum`:

```csharp
public class StudentScoreSum
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int ScoreSum { get; set; }
}
```

, the implementation could be as follows:

```csharp
List<StudentScoreSum> scoreSum = db.Scores
    .GroupBy(s => s.StudentName)
    .Select(scoresByStudent => new StudentScoreSum {
        StudentName = scoresByStudent.Key,
        ScoreSum = scoresByStudent.Sum(s => s.Score)})
    .ToList();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3BOLx).

---

##### The `.GroupBy()` return value

Assuming the data type of the entries in the `Scores` database table is in fact `Score`, the `.GroupBy()` operation returns an `IEnumerable<Grouping<string, Score>>`.

In the `.Select()` operation, `scoresByStudent` is hereby a `Grouping<string, Score>`;

- `string` being the data type of the **group key**
- `Score` being the data type of the **elements in the group's object collection**

Based on your example score data, the result from the `.GroupBy()` operation will be three groupings. They can be visualized as:

| Key | Object collection |
| --- | --- |
| "Bob" | `{ StudentName = "Bob", Score = 5 }` `{ StudentName = "Bob", Score = 5 }` `{ StudentName = "Bob", Score = 5 }` |
| "John" | `{ StudentName = "John", Score = 4 }` `{ StudentName = "John", Score = 4 }` |
| "Michael" | `{ StudentName = "Michael", Score = 3 }` `{ StudentName = "Michael", Score = 3 }` `{ StudentName = "Michael", Score = 4 }` |

For each of these three groups, a `StudentScoreSum` object is created, using the group's **key** as the `StudentName` and summing the `Score` values of all elements in the group's **object collection** to produce the `ScoreSum`.